# How should be this on java 7?

Tags: java

How should be this on java 7?

```
conversions.putAll(success);
failed.forEach((id, cnt) -> {
  conversions.merge(id, cnt, Integer::sum);
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear be specific.

Comment: For(Integer id : failed){cnt = id * id; sum += cnt;}

Comment: how should be written this code using java 7.this is on java 8? can some body explain

Comment: What are the types of `id` and `cnt`?

Comment: while (rs.next()) {
              int status = rs.getInt("status");
              int count = rs.getInt("count");
              String bankid =rs.getString("bankid");

              if (status == 1) {
                  success.put(bankid, count);
              }else {
                  failed.put(bankid, count);
              }
   }
   conversions.putAll(success);
   
   failed.forEach((id, cnt) -> {
      conversions.merge(id, cnt, Integer::sum);
   });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
conversions.putAll(success);
// you haven't told us the key type, so I just use Key here
for (Map.Entry<Key, Integer> entry : failed.entrySet()) { 
  Key id = entry.getKey();
  Integer old = conversions.get(id);
  if (old != null) {
    conversions.put(id, old + entry.getValue());
  } else {
    conversions.put(id, entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: is this the fastest optimization ?